# How to select newest records from table with many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables.Table `Products` in which there are two product types `ProductType_1` and `ProductType_2`, and second table `ProductType_2_Items` in which I keep the information that `ProductType_1` is contained in `ProductType_2`. I need to get the latest (published_at) `ProductType_1` for each `ProductType_2`.

Products table:

```
|id | published_at        | type          |
|---|---------------------|---------------|
| 1 | 2019-04-24 08:23:35 | ProductType_1 |
| 2 | 2019-05-24 08:23:35 | ProductType_1 |
| 3 | 2019-06-24 08:23:35 | ProductType_1 |
| 4 | 2019-04-24 08:23:35 | ProductType_1 |
| 5 | 2019-05-24 08:23:35 | ProductType_1 |
| 6 | 2019-05-24 08:23:35 | ProductType_2 |
| 7 | 2019-05-24 08:23:35 | ProductType_2 |
```

ProductType_2_Items table:

```
| ProductType_2_ID | ProductType_1_ID |
|------------------|------------------|
| 6                | 1                |
| 6                | 2                |
| 6                | 3                |
| 7                | 4                |
| 7                | 5                |
```

Expected result:

```
|ProductType_1_ID | published_at        | ProductType_2_ID |
|-----------------|---------------------|------------------|
| 3               | 2019-06-24 08:23:35 | 6                |
| 5               | 2019-05-24 08:23:35 | 7                |
```

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: What version of Mysql are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select A.id,p.published_at,a.ProductType_2_ID from
(
   select ProductType_2_ID,max(ProductType_1_ID) as id
   from ProductType_2_Items
   group by ProductType_2_ID
)A inner join Products p on p.id=A.id
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enought in my post but I need newest ProductType_1 by `published_at`.

Comment: @Conrad.B, have u checked my answer - it must be worked

Comment: I checked and unfortunately not working. Maybe because it's not based on published_at date.